How to get a websites data with the input from a cell Excel
I'm trying to make a excel workbook for a game called torn city. I want users to be able to input their game key into a cell and then excel automatically pulls the data from a link with the combined key.
For example this is my key(VNWZibo54fSCUM01) and link for the data is: https://api.torn.com/user/?selections=honors&key=VNWZibo54fSCUM01
Now when you go to this specific website it shows the awards that you have gotten for the game, It is in a JSON format with the two things in it being honors_awarded and honors_time.
I want the honors_awarded list to be displayed when a user inputs his key into a cell.
I have been able to get the data in excel with this url(https://api.torn.com/user/?selections=honors&key=VNWZibo54fSCUM01)
How this data looks

but I want to have a more user friendly interface.
I want this done by simply having users input their key into a cell the the data appears
Might be irrelevant but I also have this python code that does the get the data i want but I dont know if this will be able to be in excel
import requests

api = input("Enter your api key")

url = f"https://api.torn.com/user/?selections=honors&key={api}"
response = requests.get(url)
 
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()  # Parse JSON response into a Python dictionary
    if 'honors_awarded' in data:
        honors_awarded = data['honors_awarded']
        for data_list in honors_awarded:
            print(data_list)
    else:
        print("The key 'honors_awarded' does not exist in the response.")
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve data:", response.status_code)

Any suggestions?

Is Excel is something crucial for you, or you just need table-like representation of your data?

Yes the community uses excel and google sheets mostly

Seems like you'd want to to use Xlwings for this.

Created simple solution using pandas, although not very convenient because requires several steps:

Create Excel file file.xlsx in the same dir with Python script
Enter API key into Excel's first cell
Save and close Excel file
Run script
Open Excel file, data will be there:


Code:
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
try:
    key = df.columns.values[0]
except IndexError:
    print('API key not found!')
    exit()

response = requests.get(f'https://api.torn.com/user/?selections=honors&key={key}')
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    if 'honors_awarded' in data:
        df = pd.DataFrame({key: data['honors_awarded']})
        try:
            df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
        except PermissionError:
            print('Permission denied! You need to close Excel file!')
    else:
        print('The key "honors_awarded" does not exist in the response.')
else:
    print('Failed to retrieve data:', response.status_code)

